# How to redirect user if direct access image files by browser? [nginx]

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

How do I redirect if a user tries to direct access image files in browser only? I want to keep the ability to embed images with `<img src="...">`. How to redirect from

`https://img.example.com/c/600x1200_90_webp/img-master/img/2022/01/03/08/04/54/95259215_p0_master1200.jpg`

to

`https://example.com/detail?id=95259215`

This is my nginx conf

```
location ~ "^/c/600x1200_90_webp/img-master/img/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/(?<filename>.+\.(jpg|png|webp))$" {
    return 301 https://example.com/detail?id=$filename;
}
```

Code isn't working cause it's going to `https://example.com/detail?id=95259215_p0_master1200.jpg` but I need it to trim the string after the last digit of the filename so in this case trim off `_p0_master1200.jpg`. I also don't know how to make it if user is accessing it through browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression `(?<filename>.+\.(jpg|png|webp))$` captures the whole filename to the filename variable. To exctract only part before `_` to variable, use the following instead:

```
(?<filename>[0-9]+).+(?:jpg|png|webp)$
```

This one only matches numbers for the `filename` variable (I would call it `image_id` to be more descriptive). https://regexr.com is a good tool for working with regular expressions.

For limiting display only to browsers, you need to use [nginx http referer module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html).

These two combined, the configuration would look like:

```
location ~ "^/c/600x1200_90_webp/img-master/img/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/(?<filename>[0-9]+).+(?:jpg|png|webp)$" {
    valid_referers server_names;
    if ($invalid_referer = "0") {
        return 301 https://example.com/detail?id=$filename;
    }
}
```

nginx will check the HTTP Referer value. If it contains the name specified in `server_name` field, it will send the redirect. The referer field is set by browser when it loads resources for a web page.